# How to remove an unclosable desktop from desktop list?

Tags: macos, sleep-wake, big-sur, desktop

I have noticed of late that when my mbp goes into sleep mode, waking from it is essentially like a recovery (or an attempt to) which generally loses my desktop and window(s) arrangement (everything is restarted) however, some maximised windows/desktops become uncloseable see middle desktop in the image below:
[image: uncloseable_desktop_list_screen_cap]

Is it possible to remove this without having to restart the system?

**Note**:

1. I have already tried quitting the iTerm app but the (dead) full screen desktop remains.
2. I thought there might be a zombie process linked to this but grepping for zombie processes `ps -A -ostat,ppid,pid,command | grep -e '^[Zz]'` revealed nothing.
3. Restarting finder doesn't work either.
4. The only thing that works thus far involves ending my session (restarting my system).

Below are my system specs:

[image: System_specs]

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to try get to the root of the waking issue? That Space isn't "uncloseable", it's a full-screen app. Fullscreen Spaces don't have the close X. Switch to the app & either take it out of fullscreen or quit it.

Comment: @Tetsujin Already tried that before asking.

Comment: It's always best to mention in your initial what you've already tried & how it failed. It saves people wasting their time & yours.

Comment: @Tetsujin The first point in my note mentions that I tried quitting the app.

Comment: …which was added several days after I mentioned it. Much better, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just log out to clean this up. The app didn’t exit cleanly - do you force quit things or in this case or did iterm quit on its own cleanly or by command?

---

This is normal for an application that had a windows change to full screen mode. (iTerm in your cases but the process follows for any app)

- Close the window or go to that space and minimize the window and/or toggle the full screen control
- Quit the app (this may be necessary if [the developer didn’t follow the design guidelines)](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/macos/app-architecture/fullscreen-mode/)
- Launch the app again and go into and out of full screen one time
- Log out of macOS to complete clean up if needed - no need to restart unless the mission control is still out of sync when you log in again

Usually there’s no need to restart the computer but occasionally an app crashes hard enough to need the Apple menu log out option.

Comment: The app was actually closed (quit) before I asked the question. I will edit the question to reflect this.

Comment: You can proceed with the steps, lots of people won’t be on that step and be helped. Thanks for the good question @DarkStar1

Comment: Thanks anyways. I wanted to know  how to remove the dead desktop without having to end my session (logout and restart the system)

Comment: Your system state is messed up, so short of directly manipulating the memory of window server, logging out handles that cleanup. You don’t have to restart the OS, but your system has runtime corruption. Does this happen often or can you make it happen again @DarkStar1 ?

Comment: Seems to happen a lot these days, but only really with iTerm2 and, usually, when I have it in Fullscreen mode close the laptop for a while and get back to it much later.